# Python Multiprocessing: Use in Nested Function

Tags: python, function, python-multiprocessing, nested-function

I found this code online:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def foo(n):
    for i in range(10000 * n):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name="Foo", args=(10,))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

Is it somehow possible to use that code inside a function? Something like:

```
def test():
    def foo(n):
        for i in range(10000 * n):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name="Foo", args=(10,))
        p.start()
        time.sleep(10)
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

While I tried it there was always an error. But i'm still quite new to python and have most of the time no Idea what I'm really doing. Or is there maybe any alternative? (I'm using windows so SIGALRM is probably no alternative)

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Try moving the definition of foo() outside test.  I could believe that mp doesn’t like calling a nested function.

Comment: @FrankYellin Omg I'm so dump. Its such a simple answer to move foo outside of test but keep the rest inside this function to call it afterwards :D Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: You probably don't need the `__name__ == '__main__'` wrapper either.  That's only necessary for top-level code, not for code within a function.